# What are my options when trying to adhere felt to a 3D crocheted surface?

Tags: yarn, felt

I was playing OverWatch and saw these guys in an arcade box.

[image: Turnip looking things]

I started making the green and white parts. What my wife now calls the cute turnip. I am going to use felt for the facial features. Here is what I have so far:

[image: Crocheted turnip thing]

I was considering a large swatch of white for the face and affix the black eyes and mouth on top of that. The white would take up a large contoured surface. Even if I get talked out of doing it this way it would be nice to know what my options are. Gluing comes to mind but there is not a good gluing surface behind it for a good bond. Sewing has a similar issue with not enough to sew into. Ideally I would like to hid how it is attached.

Help me make my silly turnip thing!

Comment: I'd probably just use a heavy duty glue such as e6000 or any other glue that can used with fabric and is machine washable (those ones tend to be stronger). Despite the small surface area, I think you could still get a good hold with it.

Comment: I achieved good result with fabric glue, even on small pieces. Needle felting can give you finer details, but the felting needles and yarn fibers can be difficult to find depending on where you live.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like a perfect use case for **needle felting**. Instead of using ready-made sheets of felt, use the loose fibers of rowing or batting to create the felted face right on the spot.

With a bit of practise you can achieve colour effects similar to painting by layering and mixing different colours, like the blushing cheeks in your turnips.

Instructions abound on the net. [Felt Alive's](http://www.feltalive.com/links.htm) seems pretty exhaustive, covering many aspects and with ambitious projects.

[LilBlueBoo.com](http://www.lilblueboo.com/2012/02/basic-needle-felting-a-tutorial.html) shows how to make a face on a base and [Craftsy.com](http://www.craftsy.com/blog/2014/12/needle-felting-for-beginners/) has an image on a knit base, similar to your project:

[image: Butterfly felted on mittens]

Comment: My friend had recommended felting to me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Embroider or chrochet the face on it, then put the whole thing in the washing machine, so it is felted completely. Though you've already stuffed it, and you probably don't want that to be felted as well. So this is probably an idea if you can remove the filling, or if you're planning to make another one.

Comment: Not all yarns will become "felted" if run through a washing cycle or two. It depends a lot on what OP started with. For proper washer-felting, you need to calculate shrinkage etc. as well.

Comment: You're right about that not everything can be felted. If the yarn can be felted though, and the crocheted/embroidered face is made of the same yarn, then shrinking should not be a major problem as it all will shrink the same amount.